# what i have to do to put one imagem above the heading at this code?

Tags: html, css

I have this code but i can't center the image above the heading.
i tried allign/center etc but the image only stuck in the left of the web page. And i wanted to put in the center above the heading so i need help with this ç-ç if u guys can help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Teste!</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            body {
                font-family: Lobster;
            }
            .background-wrap {
                position: fixed;
                z-index: -1000;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            #video-bg-elem {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
            }
            .content {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                z-index: 1000;
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
            }
            .content h1 {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 65px;
                font-weight: 300;
                color: #fff;
                padding-top: 15%;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .content p {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 20px;
                letter-spacing: 3px;
                color: #aaa;
            }
            .circular {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                border-radius: 150px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
                -moz-border-radius: 150px;
                background: url(http://data.whicdn.com/images/246284024/large.jpg) no-repeat;
            }

        </style>


    </head>
    <body>
        <script> alert("Teste site")</script>

        <div class="background-wrap">
            <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop"> 
                <source src="vid/kappa.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Video not supported
            </video>
        </div>


        <div class="content">
            <img src="">                 
            <h1>Só queria por uma imagem em cima dessa linha.</h1>
            <p>Teste teste teste</p>
        </div>

<div class="circular">

</div>

    </body>
</html>`enter code here`
```

Comment: By saying "Image" you mean the `<video>` tag? because I don't see any Image - not as `<img>` and not as `background-image`, so please make your question more clear

Comment: Sorry i forget to put the image code look in the CSS part

Comment: are you just trying to center it? if so add `margin: auto` to `.circular`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the `<img/>` tag in the following code:

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="">                 
    <h1>Só queria por uma imagem em cima dessa linha.</h1>
     <p>Teste teste teste</p>
</div>
```

If so, you have to give width to your image and then put it's margin to auto:

```
.content img {
    width: 200px; // This value is for test;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thx for helping.